# Is adding links within profile About Me text not working correctly?

Tags: support, profile-page

I was trying to update the text on my profile that includes a couple of links for which the Markdown was generated using the Hyperlink button on the toolbar e.g.

```
<p>[Email][1] and [Twitter messages][2] from stackoverflow members welcome.</p>


  [1]: http://example.org
  [2]: http://twitter.com/example
```

However, this is just rendering as:

[Email][1] and [Twitter messages][2] from stackoverflow members welcome.

Have I formatted something wrongly or is this currently not working correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you have an unnecessary `<p>` tag in there? That will complicate matters.

See:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html

Comment: Thanks Jeff, removing the `<p>` tags fixes it. I haven't edited my profile for a long time so in the past the unnecessary tags must not have caused a problem.